# Test class passes in MavensMate, but fails in Apex Test Execution

Tags: apex, unit-test, failing-tests, mavensmate

Basically subj:

Some of my test classes pass when I run them in *MavensMate*, but fail when I run them in *Apex Test Execution* in the org itself.

*MavensMate*:

[image: MavensMate testclass]

*Apex Test Execution*:

[image: Apex Test Execution testclass]

And just because I think it might be useful for a good answer, the error(same error for all 5 methods) that I get in *Apex Test Execution* is:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MIXED_DML_OPERATION, DML operation on setup object is not permitted after you have updated a non-setup object (or vice versa): GroupMember, original object: Account: []

**So the question is:**
What could be the reason of such a different behaviour?

Comment: Seems related to http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54301/mixed-dml-exception-when-creating-permissionsetassignment-in-test-class

Comment: @Eystornt thanks for your comment, but the question is a bit different. I want to know the reason why the same test class fails in the browser, but passes in *MavensMate*

Comment: hey @Novarg after run test class in mavensmate. have you got code coverage?

Comment: Hi @Ratan. Yes, I do see the code coverage in *MavensMate*

Comment: I think it's not related to MavensMate and it's more related to the API that is used to run tests. Did you try to run you test class in Dev Console? What results do you get? I think "Apex Test Execution" UI (old) uses Metadata API and MavensMate (Dev Console) uses Tooling API to execute the test run.

Comment: @steals I just tried to run this test class in *Dev Console*, but the results are the same as with *Apex Test Execution*, all 5 methods fail with the same error

Comment: In this case I think it can be either a MavensMate issue or you have outdated version of your test class on your local pc. Because I have the same error (Mixed DML Operation) in MavensMate (v7.0.0-beta.1 on Mac) and SF UI if my test tries to update Setup and non-Setup objects. And this is correct behaviour.

Comment: When running in 'Apex Test Execution', are you using the option 'Disable Parallel Apex Testing'? If your test classes are attempting to setup custom settings, they may run into conflicts if running at the same time.

Comment: @steals I'm using *MavensMate for Sublime Text v6.0.0* on Mac. vreeder yes, the *Disable Parallel Apex Testing* checkbox is checked.

Comment: MavensMate uses the Tooling API, which is different than the API used by SFDC itself while running tests. I've seen this happen before. The answer by Daniel below is as good as it gets on how to work around the problem, but keep in mind that in these cases Mavens is wrong and Salesforce is right.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This sort of thing has been going on since the Summer '08 release. See [How to avoid MIXED_DML_OPERATION error in Salesforce tests that create Users](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2387475/54026).

Essentially, there are certain types of sObjects that you can't perform DML operations on in a test case and then proceed to modify other types of sObject. See [sObjects That Cannot Be Used Together in DML Operations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_non_mix_sobjects.htm)

> The following sObjects can’t be used with other sObjects when performing DML operations in the same transaction:
>
> - GroupMember
>   You can only insert and update a group member in a transaction with other sObjects in Apex code saved using Salesforce API version 14.0 and earlier.

The typical solution to this is to use [`System.runAs`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm) to separate the sObject types that can't have DML performed together.

> **Other Uses of runAs**
>
> You can also use the runAs method to perform mixed DML operations in your test by enclosing the DML operations within the runAs block. In this way, you bypass the mixed DML error that is otherwise returned when inserting or updating setup objects together with other sObjects.

**Why is MavensMate behaving differently than the Salesforce UI?**

Again, this oddity comes back to how the test is being run. I encountered it in [2011](http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/06/update-salesforce-custom-setting-from.html) when Eclipse gave different test results to the Salesforce UI. External tools like MavensMate and the Force.com IDE rely on using the public APIs to perform test runs.

In the case of MavemsMate, it currently runs the test cases via the [mm executable](http://mavensmate.com/API/Overview) with the [`test`](https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate/blob/master/lib/mavensmate/test.js) operation (possibly [unit_test](http://mavensmate.com/API/Debugging)). Maybe if you can read node.js fluently you can find which specific API call is being made.

Anyway, one or more of the Salesforce APIs that can be used to run test cases produce a different result to the standard Salesforce UI. There are several options to running test cases, such as the Tooling API, Metadata API or the Apex API. Then there are SOAP and REST versions available.

This may be as specific as the API version that the calls are being made against. The Salesforce UI, including the developer console, will be using current API version. Whereas the external tooling may be several releases behind.