# Does MIXED_DML_OPERATION behave differently in test methods depending on how you run them: Test Execution vs. Deployments?

Tags: apex, unit-test, deployment, mixed-dml

We typically validate our source control nightly and run all tests. This is essentially a **validate only deployment running all tests** against production. **All tests pass**.

However, if we were to run tests through **Apex Test Execution** or through **Dev Console/IDE** in production, there are several test methods that **fail** with a `MIXED_DML_OPERATION`.

The exception is *correct*, we can update the methods to use `System.runas()` and get the test methods working correctly, but I'm more interested in whether this is expected? I saw this previous [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/99644/test-class-passes-in-mavensmate-but-fails-in-apex-test-execution) about differences when running tests in Mavenmate, but this is different with running a test method on its own vs. in a deployment/validation.

---

I know more CPU time is allocated for tests running in a deployment context vs. running the test on its own so I suspect this might be another thing Salesforce treats differently in deployments.

However, *I can understand the difference in CPU time whereas I can't quite understand this behavior*.

I also tested in a sandbox using the code example in their [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_non_mix_sobjects_test_methods.htm). I removed the `System.runAs()` so it should fail. This test fails in Dev Console, but passes in a deployment/validation.

```
@isTest
private class MixedDML {
    static testMethod void mixedDMLExample() {  
        User u;
        Account a;
        User thisUser = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
        // removed System.runas() to throw mixed_dml
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='System Administrator'];
        UserRole r = [SELECT Id FROM UserRole WHERE Id = 'Id here'];
        u = new User(alias = 'jsmith', email='jsmith@acme.com', 
            emailencodingkey='UTF-8', lastname='Smith', 
            languagelocalekey='en_US', 
            localesidkey='en_US', profileid = p.Id, userroleid = r.Id,
            timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles', 
            username='testjsmith@acme.com');
        insert u;
        a = new Account(name='Acmetest123');
        insert a;
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

*Edit: I've created a support case as well*

Comment: odd -- I've never seen this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Received the following [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000335292&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1) from Support

> **During deployments we do not run mixed DML operation checks**, whereas via the UI we do (either 'Run All Tests' or running a test for an individual class). If the differences between the test failures seen in the UI compared to the deployment is solely down to 'MIXED_DML_OPERATION' errors, then **this can be deemed expected behavior as we intentionally do not check these in a deployment.**

Apparently, they do not run MIXED_DML checks for deployments and the difference I'm seeing is *expected*.